# Почему скрипт увеличивает введённое время на 33 минуты?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть скрипт, который при вводе времени в столбец A или B должен подставить к введённому времени текущую дату.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getColumn() === 1 || range.getColumn() === 2) {
    var time = range.getValue();
    if (typeof time === 'object') {
      var hours = time.getHours();
      var minutes = time.getMinutes();
      var date = new Date();
      date.setHours(hours);
      date.setMinutes(minutes);
      date.setSeconds(0); // Обнуляем секунды
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd.M HH:mm');
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()).setValue(formattedDate);
    }
  }
}
```

Но, после ввода в ячейку например 14:00 значение сначала меняется на 25.11.2023 14:00, а затем сразу же на 25.11.2023 14:33.
**С чем это может быть связано?**

При замене date.setMinutes(minutes); на date.setMinutes(minutes - 33); в ячейке выводится реально введённое время -33 минуты (25.11.2023 13:27).

Comment: вероятно так происходит из-за `Session.getScriptTimeZone()`, попробуйте указать например `'GMT+03:00'` и проверьте поведение скрипта

Comment: Вы имеете в виду вот так: Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT+03:00', 'dd.M HH:mm'); ?
Всё равно добавляет 33 минуты.
И вот так: var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'Europe/Moscow', 'dd.M HH:mm');  **не помогает**.

Comment: Проверьте часовой пояс в настройках таблицы. Файл -> Настройки -> Часовой пояс. Убедитесь, что указан ваш часовой пояс

Comment: В настройках был указан часовой пояс "(GMT+03:00) Istanbul".  Поставил "(GMT+03:00) Minsk" - время начало добавляться на 40 минут ..) Установил "(GMT+03:00) Moscow+00 - Moscow"  всё стало работать ровно.  Хотя на компьютере стоит "(UTC+03:00) Минск".

Comment: Благодарю @zxnuclear за подсказку.